# Django static are not getting load on AWS using Nginx

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

i have a website build on Django. everything is working fine on local machine but the static file are not getting load on production. Django project is running fine on Debug=False I did install

```
whitenoise==6.2.0
```

the error
[image: browser errors]

django settings

```
 SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://54.234.143.251",
]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://54.234.143.251",
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # app
    
    "applipsync",
    "store",
    # packages
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "rest_framework",
    "django_q",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "crispy_forms",
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware", #add whitenoise
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "core.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = "core.wsgi.application"

# EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

# Make email verification mandatory to avoid junk email accounts
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ""
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ""

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# settings.py example
Q_CLUSTER = {
    "name": "pdm",
    "workers": 1,
    "recycle": 500,
    "timeout": 60,
    "retry": 120,
    "compress": True,
    "save_limit": 250,
    "queue_limit": 500,
    "cpu_affinity": 1,
    "label": "Django Q",
    "daemonize_workers": False,
    "orm": "default",
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

# settings.py

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

# PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') ##specify static root

print("BASE_DIR ", BASE_DIR)
print("------------------------------------------")
print(STATIC_ROOT)

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates").replace("\\", "/"),
)
```

path in aws
[image: folder info]

Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.234.143.251;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    sendfile on;
    # to avoid any error while fetching fevicon
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/lipsync-website/app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/ubuntu/lipsync-website/app/media/;
    }
    location / {
        # communicate via socket file created by Gunicorn
        # proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/lipsync-website/app/core.sock;  
        proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

i did change the path of nginx but still the static files are not getting load on production.

[image: the project look like this]

[image: the project should look like this]

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` after deploy?

Comment: yes i did run that

Comment: And you see your files in `/home/ubuntu/lipsync-website/app/staticfiles/`, right?

Comment: yes my Django admin files are in staticfiles folder and other website static files are in static folder. i did try same setting on digitalocean and it work. idk for some reason it was not working on free AWS server.